# Grails code pull from Git works on all machines but one

Tags: git, grails, groovy, ggts

So I'm working on a project with three other developers and we are using the Grails language and are performing our development in the Groovy Grail Tool Suite. We have been moving on at a good pace but today after one of our team members pushed her code she could run the project but not visit the main page but instead got this page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCqp4.jpg (sorry not enough rep to put it inline)

My natural response was to roll back her the code (which we did) and then run it, but that did nothing to remedy the issue. Whats most perplexing is we all have the exact same code and the three of us can run the project and visit that page except her. The file it says cannot be found is present in her project and in the right directory. Any help would be great, this is a very odd issue that I've never seen before.

Comment: `grails clean`, `rm -rf target`, `grails package` ?

Comment: You're absolutely right! If you want you can put it as an actual answer and I'll check it right and get you some points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all is fine with other machines, then the problem is with the one in question.  Make sure, that the build is correct.  If your project structure holds parts of the build in `~/.grails/` do a `grails clean` otherwise just delete the project's `target` directory entirely.  Then do `grails package` to build the project.  While you do this, make sure to close your IDE or running grails instances.